# Inserting record in two different but identical tables, Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I have 2 tables which corresponds to 2 classes

```
class temp{
@Id
int x;
String name;

}

class perm{
@Id
int x;
String name;

}
```

lets say temp_customer and  perm_customer

both are identical

I want to insert record from temp_customer to perm_customer.

But doing it  with hibernate generates a new id in perm_customer and copies all other records . I want same id of the temp_customer in perm_customer also.

Comment: show the code how you are saving records in perm_customer table.

Comment: Why you need two different table with same data?

Comment: Are you trying to create a foreign key relationship?

Comment: you question is "I want to insert record from temp_customer to perm_customer" you want copy data from one table to another? or want to insert in both table at a time ?

Comment: @yogeshprajapati I want to copy the data from one table to another.

Comment: than you can use core functionality of db, use Trigger.

Comment: I am using auto_increment functionality of Mysql but still problem exists. If i add records directly in Mysql with custom value of "x"(id) it works but not with hibernate save() method

Answer (score 0):

perm table will have its own primary key and add foreign key relationship with temp.
Below is the table structure for temp and perm

```
class temp{
@Id
int x;
String name;

}

class perm{
@Id
int y;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="x")
temp t;

String name;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It receives a new ID simply because you have an ID generator. If you remove the ID generation, you will be free to explicitly set the ID field.

If you still need a unique ID for other cases, it should be easy to extract from a global sequence (or whatever your DB supports)